# importing a module file into python

Tags: python

I am beginning to learn python. I wrote the following module file to be imported into python, but the output in IDLE does not show anything. Please help

```
def main():
    print("This program illustrates a chaotic function")
    x=eval(input("enter a number between 0 and 1:"))
    for i in range(10):
        x=3.9*x*(1-x)
        print(x)

main()
```

I used 
    `import chaos` 
command to import the module, but it doesn't show any output.

Comment: Is this file called exactly `chaos.py` (starting with lowercase and ending with `.py`?) Have you put it into the correct directory?

Comment: Also your indentation is off, please correct it

Comment: you can also paste an image in the question.

Answer (score 2):

-------chaos.py----------

```
def main():
    print("This program illustrates a chaotic function")
    x=eval(input("enter a number between 0 and 1:"))
    for i in range(10):
        x=3.9*x*(1-x)
        print(x)
```

-------fileimport.py---------

```
import chaos
chaos.main()
```

**Note** Both these files should be in same directory

```
Parent Folder
          |
          |----chaos.py
          |----fileimport.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Main.py

```
import chaos
print(chaos.hello())
```

chaos.py

```
def hello():
   return "hello"
```